# How to find complete text of Interop Word wildcard search

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am using the  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

```
range.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
range.Find.Text = "#sg*";
range.Find.ClearFormatting();

while (range.Find.Execute())
{
    // create a local Range containing only a single found string
    var tagname = new Tags
    {
        TagName = range.Text
    };
```

I can't retrieve the original text the wild card matched. for e.g #sgdate is the whole word match but only getting back the wild card porting when I ask for range.text. How do I get the full text

Answer (score 0):

After further study of the code only the replaced items have a # so just search for wild card on hash you can add the hash when you are constructing the text

Comment: document.Range(start, end).Text.TrimEnd()